# Google Spreadsheet: Incomplete import of Google Finance share prices

Tags: google-sheets, google-finance

I am using the following Google Spreadsheet function to import share prices from Google Finance:

```
=importData("http://www.google.com/finance/historical?q=NASDAQ:AAPL&startDate=
Dec+2,+2000&num=30&cid=22144&output=csv")
```

The import seems to work. However, I get only values back to the year 2012 and not to 2000 (as requested). If I download the CSV file directly, it contains the correct date range.

What is wrong with my request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
=GoogleFinance("AAPL","price",date(2000,12,2),DATE(2012,12,2),1)
```

Please ensure that your dates are as per your spreadsheet settings (US/UK):